# PHP Login using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I got 3 files which is connection.php, work.php, and login.php
I am currently working with log-in.

The name of my database is wildlife and it has a field of 
**wrd_username(for username) AND wrd_password(for password)**

I am having a difficulty because the SQL is unable to detect the username and password.

MySQL is required for this PHP.
Please kindly help me.

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'wildlife');
if (!$conn) 
{
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysql_errno());
}
else
{
    echo ("connected from connection.php");
}?>
```

**work.php**

```html
  <?php
  include('login.php');
  ?>

  <html>
  <head><title>howww</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="login.php" method="post"> <!-- Sign In Process -->
  Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="emp_username"style="width:150">
  <br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="pass" id="emp_password"style="width:153">
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**login.php**

```
enter code here
    <?php
    // Try and connect to the database
    include('connection.php');
    $selected = mysql_select_db("wildlife",$conn)
      or die("Could not select ");

       //$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
       //$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 
        if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
                $emp_username = $_POST['emp_username'];
                $emp_password = $_POST['emp_username'];

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$user' and  emp_password='$pass'");
                if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) 
                { 
                    //check if there is already an entry for that username
                    echo "DETECTED Username AND PASS already exists!";
                }
                else
                {

                    //header("location:index.php");
                    echo(" okay");
                    //header('work.php');
                }
        }
        mysql_close();
    ?>
```

whenever I try to input the username and password it always ended up with **okay** *from login.php*

Comment: dude, time to ditch mysql and use `password_hash / password_verify`

Comment: hint: `name="user" id="emp_username"` and `name="pass" id="emp_password"`

Comment: use the `name` attribute inside `$_POST` instead

Comment: side note: you should learn about [SQL-Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - your code is very, very, very vulnerable.  also: your code can not work - where do you set the $user variable? you only set $emp_username

Comment: @Ghost hahahah. thankss

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be assigning the wrong `$_POST` variable to password variable:

```
$emp_password = $_POST['emp_username'];
```

It should be something lke:

```
$emp_password = $_POST['emp_password'];
```

Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Try learning to use [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do these changes into your login.php file

```
<?php
// Try and connect to the database
include('connection.php');
$selected = mysql_select_db("wildlife",$conn)
  or die("Could not select ");

   //$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
   //$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 
    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
            $emp_username = $_POST['user']; //name as of html form
            $emp_password = $_POST['pass']; //name as of html form

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$user' and  emp_password='$pass'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) 
            { 
                //check if there is already an entry for that username
                echo "DETECTED Username AND PASS already exists!";
            }
            else
            {

                //header("location:index.php");
                echo(" okay");
                //header('work.php');
            }
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$user` and `$pass` variable are empty always.I have update the login.php page below. Use the below code

```
<?php
        // Try and connect to the database
        include('connection.php');
        $selected = mysql_select_db("wildlife",$conn)
          or die("Could not select ");

           //$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
           //$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 
            if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
                    $user = $_POST['user'];
                    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$user' and  emp_password='$pass'");
                    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) 
                    { 
                        //check if there is already an entry for that username
                        echo "DETECTED Username AND PASS already exists!";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //header("location:index.php");
                        echo(" okay");
                        //header('work.php');
                    }
            }
            mysql_close();
        ?>
```

Comment: Hi! OMG Thankyou so muchh . BIG HELP!  AWESOME

Comment: No problem Happy coding :)

Comment: Sorry, this code just digs a deeper hole. Why is the escaping still commented out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is:

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$user' and  emp_password='$pass'");`

Should be:

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$emp_username' and  emp_password='$emp_password'");`

Looks like you just had some unused variables in your query to MySQL ($user and $pass weren't really assigned to anything).  Other than that, everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

In just 3 lines, it should like this :

```
$user = $_POST['emp_username'];
$pass = $_POST['emp_password'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$user' and  emp_password='$pass'");
```

Comment: HI~ Thankyou so much ^_^

Comment: It absolutely should **not** be this simple. This removes the escaping that should have been there but was mysteriously commented out.

Answer (score -1):

In connection.php page no need to add database with mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '','wildlife')  as you use it in login.php page mysql_select_db("wildlife",$conn) and in your query just add proper variable in where condition emp_username='$emp_username' and  emp_password='$emp_password'"

connection.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$conn) 
{
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysql_errno());
}
else
{
    echo ("connected from connection.php");
}?>
```

work.php

```
<?php include('login.php'); ?>

<html>
<head><title>PLEASE GUMANA KA NA</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post"> <!-- Sign In Process -->
Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="emp_username"style="width:150">
<br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" id="emp_password"style="width:153">
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
enter code here
    <?php
    // Try and connect to the database
    include('connection.php');
    $selected = mysql_select_db("wildlife",$conn)
      or die("Could not select ");

         if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
                $emp_username = $_POST['user'];
                $emp_password = $_POST['pass'];

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$emp_username' and  emp_password='$emp_password'");
                if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) 
                { 
                    //check if there is already an entry for that username
                    echo "DETECTED Username AND PASS already exists!";
                }
                else
                {

                    //header("location:index.php");
                    echo(" okay");
                    //header('work.php');
                }
        }
        mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much for helping :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$emp_username = $_POST['emp_username'];
$emp_password = $_POST['emp_username'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$user' and  emp_password='$pass'");
```

This snippet should change to:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$user' and  emp_password='$pass'");
```

Because the form has `user` and `pass` parameter, not `emp_username` or `emp_password`